# Sign of a one-sided limit

Tags: limits

Given the following quantity
$$
a=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)(x_0-x)~,
$$
with $f(x_0)\neq0$ and $f\in C^\infty$. Can we say that $\text{sign}(a)=-\text{sign}(\lim_{x\to x_0+}f(x))$ or this doesn't even make sense and $a=0$?

This is one of those questions that I have never thought about until someone asks it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: \to ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Jahambo99 ahah, thank you.

Comment: We *might* infer that $a=0$ - if for instance $f$ is continuous at $x_0$

Comment: $x_0 - x < 0$... and in general $\sign(a) \ne \sign(\lim_{x\to x^+_0} f(x))$, and the limit need not to exist.

Comment: @user251257 ups, forgot a minus

Comment: You've added the condition that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, which implies it is continuous, which implies $a=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases:

- $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x) $ exists

$$\implies a=0$$

- $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x) $ doesn't exist and we have no idea about $a$. It depends on $f$.

Comment: @PML Thanks for your question.